# List for python scripting puts in all characters individually

Tags: python, scripting

Here's something I just quickly typed into the "Python Console" which perfectly shows the problem I'm having:

```
>>> list = []
>>> word = "something"
>>> list.extend(word)
>>> print(list)
['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

I want to know how I can make it so that it adds "something" as just one thing. So that when I type `print(list)` the outcome looks like this:

```
>>> print(list)
['something']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined list as an array and the python console prints an array as single elements. So either define it as string or combine it to one string before printing.

or did you search for append?

```
list = []
word = "something"
list.append(word)
print(list)
```

maybe this explains it a bit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/

Comment: Using ```list.append``` did the trick. Thank you!